# Sort Names Alphabetically in C

Tags: c, sorting, struct, linked-list

I have a C structure that contains contact info for a person, such as name, phone number, etc. The "contact" structures are contained within a linked list. I need to insert nodes in a way such that the linked list is sorted into alphabetical (ascending) order.

Is there a built-in sorting function in C that I can call? Or do I have to write my own sorting function? If there is a built-in function, could I get an example of how I'd call it on a structure within a linked list?

Comment: If you have a C++ compiler around, you can take a look at the implementation of `std::list<T>::sort()`, which is probably going to be very close to what you'll have to write. It'll be contained entirely in a header file.

Comment: Is your homework based on building a linked list in sorted order or sorting in general after the list is built?  If you're just building a linked list, then you need to lookup "insertion sorted linked list", where you handle the sorting as a function of your list insertion.

Comment: @jmquigley Looking at the code more, it does appear that I have to insert the new item into the linked list based on where the name will fall alphabetically. So I'll be building the linked list up like that. Is there an example you know of where I can look at something that inserts the new item based on alphabetical order using a node?

Answer (score 2):

There's no standard sorting method for a "list". The closest is `qsort` (which can indeed sort user-defined objects) but it only works on continuous ranges (arrays and the like).

You'll probably have to implement your own sorting procedure or use and array instead of a list.

Answer (score 0):

Here is an example of code that performs an insertion sorted linked list.  This isn't a cut and paste for you, but will show you what to expect in that type of insertion:

http://www.c.happycodings.com/Sorting_Searching/code8.html

Focus on the "insert()" call.  I did not compile this code to test it, but I read it over and it looks correct to me.  It shows how to search a list and pointer adjustments.  You should be able to solve your problem from this code.